# Battery (e.g, LA, SLA, L-ion) usage recommendation

Tags: battery-storage

For the same Capacity requirement, which of the below options is better? 
1. Single battery with full capacity (AH)
2. Multiple battery (in parallel) with total same capacity (same AH).

For example, single 100AH battery is better or four 25 AH battery is better?

Use case: Home inverter 
Load -> 1 ceiling fan (80w)+ 1 Led tube light (20w) in four rooms. 
Total 400w power requirement.

Considering power factor,  approximately 400x1.15=460VA should be required. For 12v inverter battery approx current would be 40A. To run the mentioned load on battery for 2 hours about 100AH 12v battery would be required.

Comment: Both approaches have benefits and drawbacks. Need more details. What is the application? How much peak current is needed?

Comment: temperature ranges, desired life time, acceptable self-discharge rate, cost constraints, weight constraints…

Comment: Use case is in inverter at home

Comment: 1 ceiling fan (80w)+ 1 Led tube light (20w) in four rooms. Total 400w power requirement. Considering power factor,  approximately 400x1.15=460VA should be required. For 12v inverter battery approx current would be 40A. To run the mentioned load on battery for 2 hours about 100AH 12v battery would be required.

Comment: Good info. If you add it to your Q then it will be clearer.

Comment: example explanation added into the question

Answer (score 1):

Using the larger batteries will have lower initial cost, but will be less flexible in how you use it. Also, if one larger cell goes bad, the replacement cost will be more than if a smaller cell fails. And, if you choose lead-acid types, they're *heavy*.

If you have room to use multiple cells of lower voltage, this is a more serviceable solution. For example, using a bank of series-parallel 6V cells allows making a solution that can provide high peak current with less stress on the batteries. 40A is quite a lot, so splitting the draw across multiple batteries would give better life.